# MySQL "unauthenticated users" even if 'skip-name-resolve' is enabled

Tags: mysql

I'm facing an issue that i'm stuck...

We've MySQL version 5.5.21 and we've detected recently some "unauthenticated users" appears and disappears in the processlist. The DNS server is well and responding fastly. Even that, we use IP address to set privileges for MySQL users.

To be sure, i've enabled  `skip-name-resolve` option in the `my.cnf` file and restart the service. But, these requests still appear so i conclude there's something else to check but i don't know what after many investigations.

I've read that these requests can paralyzed all the TCP pool of MySQL, but in my case there's not this issue at the moment.

So, is it a beggining of dysfunctions in my MySQL server or is it just a normal behavior ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Usually people firewall MySQL to only allow access from expected ips. `skip-name-resolve` doesn't prevent people from trying to log in. If you _must_ have a world-accessible MySQL instance, you can consider putting it behind an SSH server, or running off a strange TCP port with a very high number.

Comment: I think your issue might be related to saving .cnf file with Unicode encoding. Convert .cnf file to ASCII encoding and see that if you're still having an issue.

Comment: @Evert I should be more explicit in my issue sorry. We're in a LAN environment. For example, i've a server which host a web application and out of about 15 requests form this server, i have 3, 4 requests in "authenticated users".

So i don't really understand what does it means

Comment: @Nae i'll try that, but if we can, we don't want to activate this option :)